# Emacs on Windows: how to set up Autoconf / GNU build system

Tags: windows, emacs, automake, cedet

I wish to use Autoconf / GNU build system for all my dev projects.

I'm using emacs for Windows, and I want to stay in the "windowed" mode.

I cannot get the emacs to find autoconf. More specifically, I want to do it from EDE/CEDET:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/workspace/probaEDEgeneric/" -*-
Compilation started at Mon Oct 21 12:22:10

autoreconf -f -i;./configure;
'autoreconf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon Oct 21 12:22:10
```

If I do `M-x compile`, with `bash autoreconf -f -i;./configure;`, I get

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/workspace/probaEDEgeneric/" -*-
Compilation started at Mon Oct 21 11:52:22

bash autoreconf -f -i;./configure;
ac-wrapper: Unable to locate any usuable version of autoconf.
    I tried these versions: 2.99:2.5 2.98:2.5 2.97:2.5 2.96:2.5 2.95:2.5 2.94:2.5 2.93:2.5 2.92:2.5 2.91:2.5 2.90:2.5 2.89:2.5 2.88:2.5 2.87:2.5 2.86:2.5 2.85:2.5 2.84:2.5 2.83:2.5 2.82:2.5 2.81:2.5 2.80:2.5 2.79:2.5 2.78:2.5 2.77:2.5 2.76:2.5 2.75:2.5 2.74:2.5 2.73:2.5 2.72:2.5 2.71:2.5 2.70:2.5 2.69:2.5 2.68:2.5 2.67:2.5 2.66:2.5 2.65:2.5 2.64:2.5 2.63:2.5 2.62:2.5 2.61:2.5 2.60:2.5 2.59:2.5  2.5x:2.5 2.13:2.1
    With a base name of 'autoreconf'.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Mon Oct 21 11:52:23
```

I have MinGW installed and on path

```
C:\Users\dkr85djo>bash
bash-3.1$ autconf --version
bash: autconf: command not found
bash-3.1$ autoconf --version
autoconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.68
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+/Autoconf: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>, <http://gnu.org/licenses/exceptions.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.
bash-3.1$ autoreconf --version
autoreconf (GNU Autoconf) 2.68
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+/Autoconf: GNU GPL version 3 or later
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>, <http://gnu.org/licenses/exceptions.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David J. MacKenzie and Akim Demaille.
bash-3.1$ exit
```

Comment: if `(executable-find "autoconf")` doesn't find anything, you'll need to properly configure the `exec-path` variable

Comment: @picklerick by all accounts, exec-path is supposed to pickup the PATH on emacs restart. the problem is, autoconf et al. are scripts, not executables

Comment: what is the result of the `(executable-find ...)`? scripts are executable (with exec bit set) -- is this different on window?

Comment: @picklerick nil, both for make and autoconf...

Comment: well `make` is certainly not a script, so regardless of differences on windows, it sounds like your `exec-path` isn't including ming locations

Comment: @picklerick fair enough; what happens then with M-x compile? It can find bash, for example, and that also gives nil in executable-find; cmd can be found though

Comment: `compile` is likely using `shell-file-name`, which probably points to bash for you; are you able to find other things like `gcc`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201222/discussion-between-hatebit-and-pickle-rick).